# React + React Native starter kit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am going to develop a web + mobile application using React and React Native. I'd like to share as much code as possible between React and React Native. I was looking for some starter kits, but found only [este](https://github.com/este/este). However, for me, it seems to be an overkill as it has too many dependencies (also I wasn't able to make it work for Android - when I fix some error, I run into another one).

I'd like to have just React + React Native + Redux + web bundling etc. Are there any other alternatives? Or at least very simple example apps that I could use?

Answer (score 5):

Did you check the [awesome React-native list](https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native#seeds) ?

As I said in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419036/react-native-and-react/38786325#38786325), as long as you follow the component / container pattern with Redux; you are able to reuse a lot of code.

The pattern encourages you to separate every presentational code into the comopnent. The container holds all the logic.

Then when you want to reuse the code, you just have to rewrite the component.

[Here](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.byydjh2gi) is a great explanation on how to implement it.

Also, you may want to check [React-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web). It allows you to code in react-native for the .... browser.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I now know why there aren't almost any starter kits that would combine React + React Native. **The reason is that it is not a good idea to combine web React and React Native.** Just create two separate apps, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches. For those still interested in combining the two platforms, have a look at [React Native for Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) instead.

So in the end, I've created my own started kit. You can find it here: https://github.com/gina-system/react-starter

Answer (score 0):

why do not you check out https://github.com/teallabs/react-native-init
pretty amazing react-native starter kit with codepush, google signin, sentry, react-navigations and all setup steps.